# Numpy: sums 1D array indexed by rows of 2D boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that I have an `(m,)`-array `a` and an `(n, m)`-array `b` of booleans. For each row `b[i]` of `b`, I want to take `np.sum(a, where=b[i])`, which should return an `(n,)`-array. I could do the following:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[True, False, False], [True, True, False], [False, True, True]])
c = np.array([np.sum(a, where=r) for r in b])
# c is [1,3,5]
```

but this seems quite unelegant to me. I would have hoped that broadcasting magic makes something like

```
c = np.sum(a, where=b)
# c is 9
```

work, but apparently, `np.sum` then sums over the rows of `b`, which I do not want. Is there a numpy-inherent way of achieving the desired behavour with `np.sum` (or any ufunc.reduce)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[True, False, False], [True, True, False], [False, True, True]])
c = np.sum(a*b, axis = 1)
```

output:

```
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: OK, that was too easy.